# Specific NSRegularExpression with HTML tags

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I would like to use **NSRegularExpression** in order to fetch some characters in **NSString**. I succeed to display every URL in my NSString, but that's not exactly what I want...

I would like to fetch every url beginning with the html tag like that :

`<a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/stringornumber.jpg`

For sure with stringornumber with any letter or number and accept character like "_" or "-"
Here is my code for displaying every URL but I have to change it to accept html tags and accept character like "-". I have tried many times but I can't...  :

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = 
[NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"http?://([-\\w\\.]+)+(:\\d+)?(/([\\w/_\\.]*(\\?\\S+)?)?)?" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
```

Comment: Have you tried `@"<a[^>]*>"` as your full `NSRegularExpression` pattern?

Comment: @IanMacDonald Yeah, you're right ! Now I've every URL with html markup, but I just want this kind of markup : <a href='http://www.bundoransurfco.com/wp-content/uploads/stringornumber.jpg

Comment: You are not guaranteed that `href` is the first property of an `a` tag. You'll have to be clearer about your desired end result.

Comment: @IanMacDonald No it's ok just with `@"<a[^>]*>"` ! I can make NSPredicate after on my NSArray :) Thank you man !!!